# How to get the values from Particular sites?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, asp.net-ajax

I am developing such application where I wanted to retrieve some values from the site.
for example here I am developing an finance application. 
and I wanted to take the price for the product from the google finance or yahoo finance.
how can we access this value and it will reflect to our DB?
is it possible to get the values from sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is consume APIs in your application and store the data as needed:

[Google Finance APIs and Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/finance/)

[yahoo-finance-managed](http://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/)

Comment: The links have documentation you can follow and start searching with to get examples.